# Turbolink 5 reload specific block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I use Rails 5.0.0 and Turbolinks 5

Have Turbolinks 5 ability reload only specific part of page, for example:

```
<div class='block1'>
  <span class='moo'>Moo-moo-moo!</span>
  <span class='some'>It's OK</span>
</div>
.......
<div class='block2'>
  <span class='moo'>Moo-moo twice!</span>
  <span class='some'>Change me, pls!</span>
</div>
```

and I need reload only `class='block2 some'`

can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: using jQuery maybe?

Comment: [turbolinks-classic](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic) used to it (`Turbolinks.visit(url, { change: ['id'] });`) but in version 5 I can't find it

Comment: Unfortunately, selective updating was removed in Turbolinks 5.  The contributors stated it was too complex to address properly in Turbolinks, so they left it out.  I, too, was pretty bummed when they did that, because it was a useful feature.